# Removing first and last quotations

Tags: r

I have the following vector values.

```
A<-c("‘7X6’", "‘UY8’", "‘JX0’", "‘8D8’", 
"‘RGNSW9’", "‘BH7P1’")
```

And using the code

```
paste(A, collapse = ", ")
```

Then using the code suggested I paste to the SQL Query

```
EUR<-data.frame(sqlQuery(myConn, paste("SELECT TOP 10000 [AxiomaDate]
                                      ,[RiskModelID] ,[AxiomaID],[Factor1],[Factor2],[Factor3]
FROM [PortfolioAnalytics].[Data_Axioma].[SecurityExposures]
                                      Where AxiomaID IN ('", cat(A, "\n"))))
```

This output just pastes the values and does not read the query. I have also realised I need ' type of quotation and not ’. Is there anyway I can paste the value corrected through R - having a lot of trouble here.

Comment: The first and last quotes are not part of the string, but if you want to get rid of them for print purposes try `B<-paste(A, collapse = ", ");cat(B, "\n")`.

Comment: Thanks can you tell me what the above is doing

Comment: It's outputing the string `B` as is, with no delimeters, the quotes, followed by a newline character, `\n`. When you use `print` or autoprinting is on, the delimeters are also output though they are not part of the character string. To see that they are not part of it try, for instance, `grepl('"', B)`.

Comment: Ok but I don't want it to be outputted but rather saved in string B? Essentially what I am trying to do is paste these values in an SQL query within R.

Comment: If that's what you need then you shouldn't have aproblem, like I've said the double quotes are *not* part of the string. Try to paste them into the command and see the result. If the problem still exists, then put the output in your question.

Comment: To replace the quotes with normal single quotes use `A <- gsub("‘|’", "'", A)`. And then try `paste("SELECT TOP etc Where AxiomaID IN (", B, ")")`.

Comment: Okay this is very close the sql code now does the following - everything is correct except that last quote outside the backets... AxiomaID IN ( '7X6', 'UY8', 'JX0', '8D8', 'RGNSW9', 'BH7P1' )'

Comment: That I cannot solve. Where does it come from? My `paste` instructino does not have that last quote, so I can only guess that it must be somewhere in your code.